# Шифр Цезаря, JAVA

Tags: java, while, encryption

Как дополнить алгоритм, что бы он учитывал символы по типу пробела, '!', ',', '?'.

```
public static String encrypt(String text, int key) {
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    String cyphertext = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(text.charAt(i));
        int keyValue = (key + charPosition) % 33;
        char replace = ALPHABET.charAt(keyValue);
        cyphertext += replace;
    }
    return cyphertext;
}
```

Comment: Включаете в алфавит `ALPHABET` соответствующие символы, а не только буквы, при этом используете длину строки при вычислении `keyValue = (key + charPosition) % ALPHABET.length();`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!